# **SOLVED** Fetch data from mysql column to an array and select it individually when needed

Tags: php, mysql

**EDIT: For those who don't even read, and immediately press "minus" button, if you think I didnt recearch, Ive been for 2 days looking. If you think its not usefull, for you maybe, It's not because you know it all, if you do please give the answer. If you think its unclear, ask for more info and i will clarify.**

**EDIT 2: Problem is solved, the solution is right bellow "SOLVED CODE". Thank you for everyone who participated with good ideas!**

I need to get data from a column in mysql and use it after.
Example:

```
column1
water
juice
wine
```

So i can echo

```
"In the morning I drink WATER"
"In lunch I drink JUICE"
"and at dinner I drink WINE"
```

**SOLVED CODE**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ingredients WHERE drink > '' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $array[] = $row['drink'];

   }

   echo $array[1];
   echo $array[2];
   echo $array[3];
}
```

I get a full string "waterjuicewinewaterjuicewine" and i want to select only one of it at the time. I looked up everyone but found nothing.

Comment: Thank you Anshu for helping me edit correctly my text. I'm very troubled by this problem I cant think straight anymore.

Comment: Im sorry to inform that both of your coments are irrelevant to the question, that query is working as it should be. Problem is described in tittle.

Answer (score 1):

Your result is an array, and array has indices.

So you can

```
echo $row[0]['drink'];
echo $row[1]['drink'];
```

and so on, removing the need for the while loop.

in effect you can say;

```
echo "In the morning I drink ". $row[0]['drink'];
echo "In lunch I drink ". $row[1]['drink'];
echo "and at dinner I drink ". $row[2]['drink'];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: $row[0]['drink'] and so on where 0 could be 1,2,3 etc

Comment: I get an error  "Undefined offset: 1" when i use it like that

Comment: Thank you for helping me think Will! I have found the solution. The code is updated above!

Answer (score 0):

change echo $row['drink'];

```
echo $row['drink'].PHP_EOL;
```

If you want one element, just change LIMIT 50 to LIMIT 1

Comment: I want one element, but if I change to 1, I need to call the query 50 times to get a diferent result. I was trying to get the 50 at one time, and after that select the array key when I wanted.